# StreamWriter, FileStream and windows file locks

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, locking

I am writting a small app to export and import data from database using .NET DataSets and XML and as part of that I am doing the following.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);
sw.Write(xml.OuterXml);
sw.Close();
```

The problem is that the close method closes the FileStream (file parameter passed to constructor) but doesn't release the file lock.  The file is one that the program I have written creates so I know nothing else is locking it.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is this a windows bug?

**EDIT**

Yes 'file' is a FileStream object and I naively assumed that calling close() on the stream that wraps the files stream would also cleanup and dispose the underlying file stream by calling the FileStream.close method. But i'm not sure about that any more.

Wrapping this in a using block still has the same effect.

One extra note is that the filestream object is created in a different method but that shouldn't make any difference

Comment: How do you determine that the file is still locked?  I do this kind of thing quite often, and I have never run into the problem that you describe.

Comment: Yeah, what is "file"?  Is it a FileStream?  If it is, you need to close it and it's not the OS's fault.  Like Jim, I have no problems with simple IO operations.

Comment: You can control the "anal-retentive" and "moronic" file locking. If you don't want to lock the file when you open it, say so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

Comment: Nothing wrong with Windows' file locking. I bet you had an exception thrown before your process got to `sw.Close();` and so it was left hanging. It will get released eventually. Please consider using `using()` as illustrated in The_Smallest's answer to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: as stated 'file' is a filestream object create using the stupid File static class (OOP it is not).

Comment: @Jim Mishcel i know the dam things is still locked because that is what the error tells me.

Comment: @liho1eye: While I have never seen a reproduceable case I have had many experiences with programs on occasion holding a lock on a file they had closed.  Occasionally this even persisted when the program was no longer in memory at which point the file was locked until reboot.  This has happened much more on W98 than later OSes but I have seen it on XP.  (I don't have enough experience with Vista or 7 to address them.)

Comment: @eaglestorm: You have not given us enough information to determine if it's a Windows bug or a problem with your code. Can you post a complete reproducible case, including the part that creates the file? And if you want to discuss my writing (the link you posted), we can do that offline or in the forum for that site.

Comment: Yeah, we're "noobs", but you can't figure out how file locks work.  Right.  If you have exhausted all other options, it could be the issue described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/12/10089878.aspx

Comment: why is this downvoted? None of these links suggested are relevant to the question. I get this issue where close or dispose work just fine for a while, but after some prolonged usage from an ASP/IIS process, the file gets permanently locked.

Comment: OS file locking does not have bugs. This is about the most battle tests code that you can find. This is *your* bug. There's probably some other handle opened to that file. Use Process Explorer to find the process that has it open.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
  sw.Write(xml.OuterXml);
```

(or try to call `sw.Dispose()` manually)

Comment: According to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx), `Close` calls `Dispose`.

Comment: Dosen't seem to make any difference the file is still locked when I try to open it in .NET again.

Comment: Yes, Close does call Dispose.  The problem is "file", which the OP is not closing and then blaming the OS for being "anal retentive and moron".

Comment: @Jim if the `StreamWriter` wasn't meant to be closed by disposing it, then it would not be `IDisposable`, since thats the whole purpose of `IDisposable`. The fact that Close() calls Dispose() (as opposed to other way around) is an irrelevant implementation detail.

Comment: @Ed: but `StreamWriter.Close` calls `Close` on the underlying stream.  `File` is almost certainly a `FileStream`, and `FileStream.Close` calls `Dispose`.  So the streams ARE being disposed of.

Comment: @liho1eye: No, the fact of `Close` calling `Dispose` is not at all irrelevant because it does affect the behavior of the code.  `Close` calls `Dispose` in this case, meaning that the `StreamWriter` and the underlying `FileStream` have both been disposed.

Comment: @Jim pull up Reflector and observe `Close()` and `Dispose()` having identical body. They both call private `Dispose(bool)` which is what msdn article is talking about. So, yes, it is irrelevant which one you call, both will do exactly the same thing, except in The_Smallest's variant it is shortest/cleanest solution.

Comment: @liho1eye: Yes, I'm fully aware of the implementation and what the documentation is talking about.  I also agree that `using(...)` here is the best way to do things.

Comment: @Jim then I don't really understand what is your point. Why would you downvote this answer? How is using Close() affects behavior versus Dispose()?

Comment: I did not downvote the answer. My point was that using `Dispose` instead of `Close` was not going to fix the OP's problem.

Comment: So did anyone solve the file locking in OP's question? It is soemthign i have run into many many times.

Answer (score -1):

Would it help to wrap the file stream in a using or simply use the overloaded method for creating the stream writer:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Append))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    sw.Write(xml.OuterXml);
    sw.Close();
}
```

or:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("path"))
{
    sw.Write(xml.OuterXml);
    sw.Close();
}
```

I suspect the problem is in the code creating or using the FileStream. Perhaps you could elaborate on how you use the FileStream object you create.

Comment: why are you calling `sw.Close()` inside using? Dispose should close it either way.

Comment: he probably just copy/pasted from the op